# Meteor.js sending client variable to server

Tags: javascript, meteor, methods, server, client

Basically want to do this... I thought a Meteor.method? but how would I go about that..? Thanks for help.

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
var clientVar = getElementById("someId").value ;
}

if(Meteor.isServer) {
HTTP.call( 'GET', 'http://someurl.com/' + devId + '/' + '/' + utcTimestamp + '/' + 'clientVar', {
}, function( error, response ) {
  if ( error ) {
    future.return( error );
  } else {
    future.return( response ); 
 }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

presuming on the client you'll have some sort of event that triggers the method you'd go

```
Meteor.call("useClientVar", clientVar, function(e,r) {//handle result});
```

and on the server you'd have

```
Meteor.methods({
  useClientVar(thing) {
    check(thing, String); // or whatever you're expecting
    // Do your HTTP call
  }
});
```